# Add multiple values from checkbox to array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some checkboxes on each object, and I would like to save the values.

Array of objects

```
[

    {
      "title": "Kevin Joe",
      "id": "365DmXom2V13xOqagTHczU",
      "enabledUnits": ""
    },
    {
      "title": "Kevin 2",
      "id": "365DmXom2V13xOqagTHczU",
      "enabledUnits": ""
    }

]
```

Some dummy units

```
  const dummyUnits = ["Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", "Unit 5"]
```

[image: mockup]

If I click on Unit 1 and Unit 2 For 'Kevin Joe'. This would be the desired result. Added to the object.

```
[

    {
      "title": "Kevin Joe",
      "id": "365DmXom2V13xOqagTHczU",
      "enabledUnits": "Unit 1, Unit 2"
    },
    {
      "title": "Kevin 2",
      "id": "365DmXom2V13xOqagTHczU",
      "enabledUnits": ""
    }

]
```

Current onChange handler, Is working but is just adding the single value, not multiple.

```
  const createOnChangeHandlerUnits = (floorPlan: FloorPlan, property: 'enabledUnits') => (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
) => {
    const {value} = e.target;

    setFloorPlans(floorPlans => {
        return floorPlans.map(entry => {

            if (entry.id === floorPlan.id) {
                return {...entry, [property]: value};
            }
            return entry;

        });
    });
    props.sdk.field.setValue(floorPlans);
};
```

```
{dummyUnits.map((unit, i) => {
   return (
      <CheckboxField id={unit} data-id={i} key={i} value={unit} onChange{(createOnChangeHandlerUnits(floorPlan, 'enabledUnits'))} labelText={unit} />)
})}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string concatenation as follows.

```
    setFloorPlans(floorPlans => {
        return floorPlans.map(entry => {

            if (entry.id === floorPlan.id) {
                return {...entry, [property]: entry[property].concat(`,${value}`)};
            }
            return entry;

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but that seems to be adding to only one object and not toggling the unit values e.g `enabledUnits: ",Unit 1,Unit 2,Unit 1"`

Comment: got your point.

Answer (score 1):

To toggle a value, you have to check if it's already in the string

```
if (entry.id === floorPlan.id && !entry[property].includes(value))
```

---

If it's not, I'd create an array using `split` and push the `value` inside, then `join` the values

```
entry[property].split(',').push(value).join(',')
```

---

If it is, you have to `filter` through the items to remove the toggled item, then `join` the values

```
entry[property].split(',').filter(item => item !== value).join(',')
```

---

**The whole code**

```
if (entry.id === floorPlan.id && !entry[property].includes(value)) {
  return { ...entry, [property]: entry[property].split(',').push(value).join(',') };
} else if (entry.id === floorPlan.id) {
  return {
    ...entry, 
    [property]: entry[property]
      .split(',')
      .filter(item => item !== value)
      .join(',') };
  }
}

return entry;
```

Although I don't think that's a good approach. I'd use an array as the type of `enabledUnits` for one. Maybe create a `boolean` variable to contain the toggled state. This seems a little overkill to me and also expensive to mutate the data all the time.

---

## Edit

```
const setChecked = (
  floorPlan: FloorPlan,
  property: 'enabledUnits'
) => (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const {value} = e.target;

  const item = floorPlans.find(entry => entry.id === floorPlan.id);
  return item[property].includes(value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've changed the 'enabledUnits' to be an array.

`
    setFloorPlans(floorPlans => {
        return floorPlans.map(entry => {
            if (entry.id === floorPlan.id && !entry[property].includes(value)) {
                return {...entry, [property]: entry[property].concat(`${value}`,)};
            } else if (entry.id === floorPlan.id) {
              return {
                ...entry,
                [property]: entry[property]
                  .filter(item => item !== value)};
              }
            return entry;
        });
    });
};
`

Comment: Though If i have multiple objects onChange only effects one which is strange `onChange={(createOnChangeHandlerUnits(floorPlan, 'enabledUnits'))}` would an index have to be passed through?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.. Why would you need an index? What do you mean multiple objects? You're already using an array of objects, which is technically 'multiple objects'

Comment: Sorry, ignore that. Is there a way to keep the checkbox active depending on the value saved on each object? ` <input type="checkbox" id={unit} key={i} value={unit} onChange={(createOnChangeHandlerUnits(floorPlan, 'enabledUnits'))} />`

Comment: Yes, you need to set `checked={/* calculate if active */}` which can be done like your `onChange`, but instead of mutating, you return `true` or `false` depending on the existence of the value

Comment: Map through your data structure the same way and return `true` if you find the value or `false` if you didn't. Let me know if you want me to update my answer with this

Comment: If you could that would be great.

Comment: {dummyUnits.map((unit, i) => {
                    return (
                      <input type="checkbox" id={unit} key={i} value={unit} onChange={(createOnChangeHandlerUnits(floorPlan, 'enabledUnits'))} />
                    )
                  })}

Comment: setFloorPlans(floorPlans => {
        return floorPlans.map(entry => {
            if (entry.id === floorPlan.id && !entry[property].includes(value)) {
                return {...entry, [property]: entry[property].concat(`${value}`,)};
            } else if (entry.id === floorPlan.id) {
              return {
                ...entry,
                [property]: entry[property]
                  .filter(item => item !== value)};
              }
            return entry;
        });
    });

Comment: How do i use your edit on the checkbox itself? 

                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          name={unit} id={unit} key={i} value={unit}
                          className="ControlledInput__ControlledInput___2XK3j"
                          checked={setChecked(floorPlan, 'enabledUnits')}
                          onChange={(createOnChangeHandlerUnits(floorPlan, 'enabledUnits'))}
                        />